# Averaging grade scores in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

for some reason when I average the scores, it's not the right answer i.e usually something like 2 percent or 540, even if that's not what the arithmetic answer would be. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't! As well, code runs in VS, but displays syntax error in IDLE. I have no idea if they're related, but in any case, I have no idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

```
number=1
quiz=1
mini=1
peer=1
sum=0
while number <51:
    assignment = int(input("What's your grade for assignment "+ str(number) + "?"))
    number = number + 1
    sum += assignment
    assigns = (sum // 500)*100
    assigns2 = round(assigns, 2)
while peer <4:
    peers = int(input("What is your grade for peer assignment "+ str(peer) + "?"))
    peer = peer + 1
    sum += peers
while quiz <11:
    quizzes = int(input("What's your grade for quiz "+ str(quiz) + "?"))
    quiz = quiz + 1
    sum += quizzes
    quiznos = (sum // 100)*100
    quiznos2 = round(quiznos, 2)
while mini <11:
    minisss = int(input("What is your grade for mini-project "+ str(mini) + "?"))
    mini = mini + 1
    sum += minisss
    miniz = (sum // 200)*100
    miniz2 = round(miniz, 2)
final = int(input("What was your score on the final? "))
print("CALCULATING YOUR GRADE...")
gradez = (sum/1200)*100
grader = round(gradez, 2)
print("*******")
print("The total possible points was 1100, and your total is",sum,"points! Your grade is", grader, "percent!")
print("*******")
if grader >= 90:
    print("You've gotten an A!")
elif grader >= 80:
    print("You've gotten a B!")
elif grader >= 70:
    print("You've gotten a C!")
elif grader >= 60:
    print("That's a D, sorry man!")
elif grader >= 0:
    print("You've failed the class...")
print("*******")
print("You got a", assigns2, "percent for assignments!")
print("*******")
print("You got a", quiznos2, "percent for quizzes!")
print("*******")
print("You got a", miniz2, "percent for mini projects!")
print("*******")
examity = (final / 300)*100
examity2 = round(examity, 2)
print("Your final was", final, "out of 300, for a grade of", examity2, end="!")
```

Comment: Its any data :// and im inputting just the points received, so like for example, 10, 10, 5, 10, etc

Comment: This code is really hard to follow. Consider adjusting your variable names to actually describe what they are.. e.g. instead of `minisss` call it `mini_proj_input` or something. Second, you're using `//` on integers which is floor division (assuming this is Python 3.x). If you want to handle the values as specific types (e.g. a `float` or `double`) then you should specifically cast or store it as such.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the percent score for assignments, quizzes, and mini-projects, you are using the same sum variable. This means that your test scores are still added into the sum variable when you are calculating the quiz score, and the quiz and test scores are added into the sum when calculating the mini-projects score, leading to inflated scores. In short, you are using the sum variable in two conflicting ways - both to count up the total number of points and to store the separate sum values for each specific section. If I were you, I would create a separate total points variable and possibly separate sum variables with different names for each section (or reset the sum variable to 0 for each section). Also, I think you may be missing the final score in your total sum when you calculate the student's overall grade, and when calculating that total grade, you divide by 1200 but you say the total max points is 1100, and I'm not really sure how the peer assignments work into the overall score.

For the syntax error, it could be because of the versions of Python you are running in your different environments. If so, it may have to do with the end parameter in your last print statement. This article could be useful: [Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax end=''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073639/python-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-end).